# Empty Related section?

Tags: support, bug

Originally there is a Related questions link at the right part of every posting. I find it very useful to see similar questions on Stack Overflow. But nowadays, I don't see any link at all at the Related section. I try different posts even the post with hot tag or many reputation, but still blank Related section. Is it a bug or intentionally left blank?

[image]

[image]

[image]